# Fibonacci spiral in octopus tentacles.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

How you happened to notice the presence of the Fibonacci spiral in nature it is really evident. For example, unlike octopuses, squid and cuttlefishes, the nautilus kept its stunning shell, which is well known for its elaborate internal Fibonacci spiral pattern.

Can you recommend a good reference that speaks of this, and in particular, it contains some links between tentacles and Fibonacci spiral, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the book Self made tapestry from Phillip Ball

An another one wich is pretty classical On form from D'Arcy Wentworth Thompson

but in the first place I suggest you take a look in the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXIMUkSXX0.
 It is great!

You will see that often what you get is not a Fibonacci spiral, but the logarithmic spiral (of Descartes)  check for more at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral